# LaTeX no cambia el nombre de mis referencias

Tags: latex, referencias

Quiero cambiar el nombre de la bibliografía de `Referencias` a `Bibliografía`.

```
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliografía}
```

```
\bibliography{bibliotfm.bib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

En principio con esto debería funcionar, como funciona con las listas de tablas y figuras, sin embargo me sigue apareciendo como `Referencias`.

Pongo los paquetes por si estuviese habiendo alguna interacción.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx }
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage[letterpaper,left=3.5cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage{setspace} \onehalfspacing 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    showstringspaces=false,
    commentstyle=\color{red},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}
```

Comment: Se agradece un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que cuando usas `\natbib` se debe de renombrar con `\refname` como se muestra abajo

```latex
\renewcommand{\refname}{Bibliografía}
```

La respuesta fue con ayuda de [este enlace de LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452808/change-the-title-of-references-section-when-using-natbib)

Comment: El comando  `\makeatletter` no debería estar ahí. No has usado el @ en ningún momento

Comment: Gracias, no me di cuenta. Corregido